# How can I avoid "Warning: Field 'xxx' doesn't have a default value" in Storm?

Tags: python, mysql, apache-storm

I'm just curious if there's a way to make the no default value warning I get from Storm to go away. I have an insert trigger in MySQL that handles these fields and everything is functioning as expected so I just want to remove this unnecessary information. I tried setting the default value to None but that causes an error because the fields do not allow nulls. So how do I make the warning go away?

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible for you to remove the 'IsNull' constraint from your MySQL database? I'm not aware of any where it is not possible to do this. Otherwise you could set a default string which represents a null value.